# FloatingActionButton inside a FrameLayout anchored to an appbarlayout. FrameLayout doesn't behave like FloatingActionButton

Tags: java, android, android-framelayout

I have a Floating inside a framelayout anchored to an appbarlayout. And I need that the frame behaves as a Floating.
I try to adapt for my project this excellent library

[image]
[image]

And the class extens of FrameLayout.
The classes DotsView and CircleView are for the effect like. but I need them to take the behavior of the FloatingActionButton.
Any idea?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/ivStar"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/heart_desear" />

    <cu.masi.mercato.likeButton.DotsView
        android:id="@+id/vDotsView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <cu.masi.mercato.likeButton.CircleView
        android:id="@+id/vCircle"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</merge>
```

Comment: Try this library https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton .  It is easy to use.

Comment: @Vishal Jadav Thanks for the reply. But I need an effect like the LikeButton as Twitter. Do you understand?